# Model validation errors not appearing for nested model in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a simple form for entering "brand" and "model" through a single submit button, as below:

```
<%= simple_form_for @brand, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |m| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> /Brand</legend>
        <%= m.input :name %>

        <%= m.simple_fields_for :models, Model.new do |p| %>
      <%= p.input :name %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= m.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', brands_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I have name:string in my schema for both brand and model.. and validates_presence_of :name in both models.. The form DOES work for creating the brand and model simultaneously but my error "can't be blank" only shows up for the brand field.

Thanks for any help with this issue.

Comment: Do you have accepts_nested_attributes_for :models in your brand model?

Comment: Yes. I do.. and the code works.. but say I leave 'brand' and 'model' fields empty, "can't be blank" shows up only next to the 'brand' text field.

Comment: Sounded promising.. but nope, didn't do the trick.. well it didn't break anything, but still no error message next to the model field. The validation does seem to be working, even without validates_associated.. If I just fill in the "brand name" field and click submit the new brand will not be saved in the db. In other words I must enter something in both fields for a brand to be saved, which makes me think validation is ok.

Comment: Add <%= m.error_notification %> to the top?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `m' for #<#<Class:0xabab6c0>:0xa906f00>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9667/discussion-between-dans-and-abram)

Comment: Realized what I was doing wrong. Needed to ALSO put @model = Model.new inside of the controller and put `<%= m.simple_fields_for :models, @model do |p| %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realized what I was doing wrong. Needed to ALSO put @model = Model.new inside of the controller and put <%= m.simple_fields_for :models, @model do |p| %>